# How can i use MVars to move paddles on my pingpong haskell game?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, concurrency, io-monad, program-transformation

I already have a function that moves 2 paddles in a ping pong game in haskell. I want to change so it uses MVars now.

I know that i need to change wHeld, sHeld, downHeld and upHeld to MVars but any ideas on how to change movePaddle to deal with MVars?

Also when i declare wHeld an MVars it shows a error on deriving show (Non instance for (Show MVar Bool))

```hs
data PongGame = Game
  { ballLoc :: (Float, Float)  -- ^ Pong ball (x, y) location.
  , ballVel :: (Float, Float)  -- ^ Pong ball (x, y) velocity. 
  , player1 :: Float           -- ^ Left player paddle height.
                               -- Zero is the middle of the screen. 
  , player2 :: Float           -- ^ Right player paddle height.
  , playerRPos :: Float -- posicao do player right
  , playerLPos :: Float --- posicao do player left
  , ghci :: Bool -- pausar
  , showMenu :: Bool -- mostrar o menu
  , wHeld :: MVar Bool -- segura o w
  , sHeld :: Bool -- segura os
  , downHeld :: Bool -- segura down
  , upHeld :: Bool -- segura para cima
  , playerLScore :: Int -- score do jogador left
  , playerRScore :: Int -- score do jogador right
  , paused :: Bool
  } deriving Show
```

```hs
movePaddle :: PongGame -> PongGame
movePaddle = moveLeftPaddle . moveRightPaddle 
moveLeftPaddle game
          | (wHeld game) = game {playerLPos = paddleUp (playerLPos game)}
          | (sHeld game) = game {playerLPos = paddleDn (playerLPos game)}
          | otherwise = game
moveRightPaddle game
          | (upHeld   game) = game {playerRPos = paddleUp (playerRPos game)}
          | (downHeld game) = game {playerRPos = paddleDn (playerRPos game)}
          | otherwise = game

paddleUp pos = min (pos + 10) paddleMax
paddleDn pos = max (pos - 10) paddleMin
```

Comment: Why do you want to change it so it uses MVars?

Comment: im trying to understand threads in haskell

Answer (score 2):

The way MVars work is that a value of type `MVar Bool` is an opaque "token" referencing a storage location for a `Bool`.  You create such a token and read and modify the contents of its associated storage location using IO actions.

The token itself (the `MVar Bool` value) has no `Show` instance by default.  For debugging purposes, you could add one:

```
instance Show (MVar a) where show _ = "<MVar>"
```

This will allow you to derive a `Show` instance for `PongGame` without getting an error message.  However, the values stored in the `MVars` can't be displayed by the `Show` instance without some egregious IO abuse, so you might want to consider writing a function `dumpGame :: PongGame -> IO ()` that pretty-prints the current game state with all the MVar values, letting you skip the `Show` instance entirely.

Anyway, to rewrite your program to use MVars in key `PongGame` fields:

```
data PongGame = Game
  {
  ...
  , wHeld :: MVar Bool -- segura o w
  , sHeld :: MVar Bool -- segura os
  , downHeld :: MVar Bool -- segura down
  , upHeld :: MVar Bool -- segura para cima
  ...
  }
```

you'll want to rewrite your `movePaddle` and its subfunctions to run in the IO monad:

```
movePaddle :: PongGame -> IO PongGame
moveLeftPaddle :: PongGame -> IO PongGame
moveRightPaddle :: PongGame -> IO PongGame
```

In `movePaddle`, you can replace the `.` operator with `<=<` from `Control.Monad`, which is the monadic equivalent of function composition:

```
movePaddle = moveLeftPaddle <=< moveRightPaddle
```

This is basically shorthand for:

```
movePaddle game = do
    game1 <- moveRightPaddle game
    game2 <- moveLeftPaddle game1
    return game2
```

Then, you'll need to rewrite `moveLeftPaddle` and `moveRightPaddle` to access the contents of the MVars by executing IO actions:

```
moveLeftPaddle game
  = do up <- readMVar (wHeld game)
       dn <- readMVar (sHeld game)
       case (up, dn) of
         (True, False) -> return $ game {playerLPos = paddleUp (playerLPos game)}
         (False, True) -> return $ game {playerLPos = paddleDn (playerLPos game)}
         _ -> return game
```

with `moveRightPaddle` defined similarly.

To be clear, the function call `wHeld game` is a simple, pure function call that retrieves the **token** of type `MVar Bool` associated with the `wHeld` field.  We then execute the IO action `readMVar <this_token>` to actually retrieve the `Bool` value, which we can then act on in a `case` statement to update the game state.

Elsewhere in your program, you'll need a `setup` routine that creates these MVars:

```
initGame :: IO PongGame
initGame = do
  ...
  wHeld <- newMVar False
  sHeld <- newMVar False
  ...
  return $ Game ... wHeld sHeld ...
```

and you'll presumably have some thread that's running a function like:

```
processKeyEvent :: KeyEvent -> PongGame -> IO ()
processKeyEvent event game = do
  ...
  case event of
     ...
     KeyDown 'W' -> void $ swapMVar (wHeld game) True
     KeyUp   'W' -> void $ swapMVar (wHeld game) False
     ...
```